# Which is the correct degree of the taylor polynomial of this question?

Tags: taylor-expansion, error-function

Ok, so for context purposes the problem is: to determine value of x for which the function can be replaced by the taylor polynomial if the error cannot exceed 0.001
My only confusion with the answer key is WHY THEY ASSUMED that this is a 5th degree taylor polynomial because technically the 4th degree taylor polynomial is the same. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of the Lagrange Error Bound, they computed that a fifth degree polynomial would work. If the fifth degree polynomial and fourth degree polynomial are the same, the fourth degree polynomial works as well.

Comment: OK, but if I interpret it as a 4th degree polynomial to get the lagrange error bound. my x interval comes out as -0.6544<x<0.6544 which is different?

Comment: i understand that their answer gives a more defined interval, but what reasoning led them to conclude that interpreting it as a 5th degree polynomial would give a more defined interval?